# Mysql join query multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called *facility*.
Structure looks as follows:

```
id | name
---------
1 | Hotel
2 | Hospital
3 | medical shop
```

I have an other table which is taking data from the above table and keeping multiple values in one column. View looks like below:

```
id | facilities
---------------
1 | Hospital~~medical shop~~Hotel
2 | Hospital~~Hotel
3 | medical shop~~Hotel
```

If I want to join these two tables how does the query look like?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
select overview.facilities as facility 
from overview join facility on facility.id=overview.facilities;
```

Comment: What do you expect the result of the JOIN to be?

Comment: I basically want to display the values in the second table in a list  and when i try editing the form i should be able to distinguish values that are selected(which is fetched from second table) and those which are not selected(which is fetched from first table).

Comment: There is no relation in both table u need to add a column for making relation

Comment: Obviously there is nothing linking the two tables. I suggest you take the time to learn about [joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) and foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with a bit of hackery

```
select o.facilities as facility 
from overview o 
join facility f on find_in_set(f.facilities, replace(o.facilities, '~~', ','));
```

I would highly recommend you change the way you are storing data. currently it is considered un normalized and that quickly becomes a monster to deal with

you should change your table structure to look something more like this

```
+----------+--------------+
|       facility          |
+----------+--------------+
|     id   |  name        |
+----------+--------------+
|     1    | Hotel        |
|     2    | Hospital     |
|     3    | medical shop |
+----------+--------------+

+-----------+-------------+
|        overview         |
+-----------+-------------+
|    id     | facility_id |
+-----------+-------------+
|     1     |      2      |
|     2     |      3      |
|     3     |      1      |
|     4     |      2      |
|     5     |      1      |
|     6     |      3      |
|     7     |      1      |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Code Explanation:

basically you are wanting to find the matching facilities in the overview. one handy function MySQL has is **[FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)** that allows you to find an item in a comma separated string aka `find_in_set(25, '11,23,25,26)` would return true and that matching row would be returned... you are separating your facilities with the delimiter `~~` which wont work with find_in_set... so I used [**REPLACE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to change the `~~` to a comma and then used that in the JOIN condition. you can go from here in multiple ways.. for instance lets say you want the facility id's for the overview.. you just add in the select `GROUP_CONCAT(f.id)` and you have all of the id's... note if you do that you need to add a GROUP BY at the end of your query to tell it how you want the results grouped

Comment: Thank you for this great source. I got many informtion which i had never looked in mysql. :)